# mysqli multi query not executing the queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute 3 queries to create tables within a database but it will not execute the query giving me a syntax error. Can anyone look at this code and tell me what I typed wrong to make this work? I have tried everything and I can not get the queries to execute!

```
$dh = mysqli_connect($_POST['hostname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'],           $_POST['database']);
if(! $dh )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully...<br /><br />";

$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
               `content_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `section_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
               `header` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               `sub_header` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               `date_range` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
               `content_body` TEXT NOT NULL
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

$query .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sections` (
               `section_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               `position` INT(11) NOT NULL
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

$query .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sections` (
               `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `username` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `first_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `last_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `email` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

$retval = mysqli_multi_query($dh, $query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have semi colons between the queries and you are joining them all together and running at once.

If you are running multiple queries like that you need semicolons at the end of each query

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
               `content_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `section_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
               `header` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               `sub_header` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               `date_range` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
               `content_body` TEXT NOT NULL
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

$query .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sections` (
               `section_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               `position` INT(11) NOT NULL
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

$query .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sections` (
               `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
               `username` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `first_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `last_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
               `email` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";
```

Comment: i did what you said and it kind of worked. now it loads the first two queries but not the third. my code looks just like yours above

Comment: i do not. it just displays the first two queries not the third. I am missing the third table

Comment: Sorry just noticed it, you've called your 2nd and 3rd tables the same, `sections`.  So the 3rd will not run.

Comment: wow i did not even notice lol. downside to copy paste sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolons between queries.

So you are trying to execute something like this: `<...> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1CREATE TABLE <...>`